# CMake: reading documentation and distinguishing string input from var

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to get better understanding of CMake and pouring over the documentation in order to port gRPC to windows and one thing that is really nagging me is how to distinguish a string input from variable input in the documentation. For example, take the LINK_DIRECTORIES command from CMake. It takes any number of directories but reading the documentation alone it is not clear to me if I can I pass a string variable to LINK_DIRECTORIES, a string, or either one.

For example:
If `set(DIR, "/lib");` is set, which of the following is valid:

Number 1

```
set(DIR, "/lib");
link_directories(DIR)
```

Number 2

```
link_directories(${DIR})
```

It seems like LINK_DIRECTORIES take strings and not variable(s). I found out by coding and running it but this way slows down my progress considerably since I have to do a sanity check per line. What am I missing in my understanding?

Answer (score 0):

In CMake [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/index.html), if argument's *name* is "variable", "list" or contains word "variable", then you should pass **name of the variable** via this argument.

Examples:

1. Command `set` which has signature

   ```
   set(<variable> <value>
       [[CACHE <type> <docstring> [FORCE]] | PARENT_SCOPE])
   ```

   accepts *variable name* as first argument.
2. Command flow `list(LENGTH)` which has signature

   ```
   list(LENGTH <list> <output variable>)
   ```

   accepts *variable name* as first argument (and this variable is interpreted as a *list*).
3. Command flow `string(REGEX MATCH)` which has signature

   ```
   string(REGEX MATCH <regular_expression>
       <output variable> <input> [<input>...])
   ```

   accepts *variable name* as fouth argument.

In all other cases an argument is just a *string*. So, if you want to pass value of the variable, you need to explicitely **dereference** this variable using `${}` notation.